# Source jar files in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am using eclipse and having difficulties in finding the related source jar files (including recursive dependencies) manually and linking each one of them to the 3rd party jars in the project class path.  I need the source to understand the 3rd party functionality better.

What is the simple way to address this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to move to maven build tool if you are not using it already.

You can configure the maven plug-in in eclipse to do this job for you.

Here are the commands to get the source code as well as the Javadocs by maven itself from command line.

> mvn dependency:sources
>
> mvn dependency:resolve -Dclassifier=javadoc

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is twofold:

First, you have to get (read: download) all the source jar files you need.
Second, you have to tell Eclipse how to find the source jar for a given library.

If you create an Eclipse application (a product or plug-in based on Eclipse Platform or Eclipse RCP) which uses OSGi-Bundles coming from a p2 repository, and if the p2 repository contains the sources, you can usually install the "SDK" feature of the respective project to get the sources.

However, from your question I guess that you are developing a Java application (without OSGi or Eclipse runtime). In this case, I know of no builtin feature of Eclipse which could download and attach the source code for your library jars.

As Phantom Reference said, the best way is to use a tool which is able to download all the referenced jars including their source automatically. And, yes, Maven seems to be the tool of choice, because of its automated dependency management and resolution features.

BTW, if you don't want to use Maven (e.g., because you don't know it and you don't have time to get into it), you could still manually use a Maven repository to find the source (and binary) jars of most common 3rd party libraries there.

Have a look at http://search.maven.org.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the screen shot from my eclipse Windows --> Preferences that shows how to configure Maven to download and attach the source as well as Javadocs, all automatically.  Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Instead of creating a second answer, consider updating your initial answer using the "edit" link.